# SSL Certificate is not found in /var/lib/waagent/ for Linux Azure VM

Tags: linux, azure, ssl-certificate, virtual-machine, certificate-store

I am trying to add an SSL certificate for my website hosted in a Linux Virtual Machine. I added the certificate successfully doing this:

```
$certURL=(Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $key).id
$vm=Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $vmName
$vaultId=(Get-AzureRmKeyVault -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VaultName $keyVaultName).ResourceId
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMSecret -VM $vm -SourceVaultId $vaultId -CertificateUrl $certURL

Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VM $vm
```

Then, I checked that the certificate was added successfully:

```
az vm secret list --name $vmName --resource-group $resourceGroup
[
  {
    "sourceVault": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/...."
    },
    "vaultCertificates": [
      {
        "certificateStore": null,
        "certificateUrl": "https://name.vault.azure.net:443/secrets/ssl/123456ABCDFG (example)"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

However, when I check in /var/lib/waagent/, I can't find the certificate *123456ABCDFG*. I don't know where it is?

Comment: If the reply helps you, could you accept it as an answer?

Comment: @NancyXiong it does, could you please add to the answer that my issue was using the old powershell commands?

Comment: Please check my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just followed the [Tutorial: Secure a web server on a Linux virtual machine in Azure with SSL certificates stored in Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-secure-web-server). When you create a VM, certificates and keys are stored in the protected `/var/lib/waagent/` directory.

In fact, the SSL certificate is referenced by the version ID in `certificateUrl`, the 123456ABCDFG is the CURRENT VERSION of your certificate in your key vault.

Check the **Version** 
[image]

Check the certificate **Thumbprint**, the certificate is indeed there.
[image]

In addition, I validated your Powershell commands with az module, it also works on my side.

```
$certURL=(Get-azKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $key).id
$vm=Get-azVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $vmName
$vaultId=(Get-azKeyVault -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VaultName $keyVaultName).ResourceId
$vm = Add-azVMSecret -VM $vm -SourceVaultId $vaultId -CertificateUrl $certURL

Update-azVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VM $vm
```

[image]

**Edit**

If you would like to run scripts developed for AzureRM module using Az module, use the `Enable/Disable-AzureRmAlias` cmdlets to add or remove aliases from AzureRM cmdlets to Az cmdlets. Refer to more details [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/master/documentation/announcing-az-module.md). The AzureRm module will be retired, it's recommended to use the new Az module.

I test your old PowerShell commands as below:
[image]